# Javascript splice is breaking on jQuery .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var results = ['one', 'two', 'one hundred', 'three'];
var removal = [];
$.each(results, function(i) {
    removal.push(i);
    if (results[i].indexOf('one') == -1){
        console.log('Removing:' + results[i] + '(' + removal[i] + ')');
        results = results.splice(removal[i], 1);
    }
});
```

I have the following code, but it is breaking after it removes the first result.

I want it to remove anything that does not contain the word 'one'.

I am guessing it is breaking because the removal order changes once one has been removed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the above code actually supposed to do? Assuming you fix the issue with the `$.each()` loop as per the answers below, still you are pushing the array _indexes_ into the `removal` array so when the loop ends `removal` is `[0,1,2,3]`. Did you intend to push the _values_ into `removal`? Also you push them in before the if test so `removal` isn't actually tracking what got removed. Within your `if` you are using `i` as an index into both `removal` and `results` even though these arrays are different lengths because you are adding elements to `removal` and removing elements from `results`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You shouldn't splice the Array while you're iterating it with `$.each()`.

Since you're changing the length of the Array, you're going beyond the final index since.

Just use a `for` loop and adjust `i` when you remove an item...

```
var results = ['one', 'two', 'one hundred', 'three'];
var removal = [];
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    removal.push(i);
    if (results[i].indexOf('one') == -1){
        console.log('Removing:' + results[i] + '(' + removal[i] + ')');
        results.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
};
```

Note that I changed this...

```
results = results.splice(removal[i], 1);
```

to this...

```
results.splice(removal[i], 1);
```

You don't want that since `splice()` modifies the original, and returns the item(s) removed.

Comment: @user1088771: Please note that I just updated the code. I didn't notice that you had `results.splice(removal[i], 1);` instead of `results.splice(i, 1);`.

Comment: As per the comment I just left under the question, if you look at the code a bit more closely you'll see that the value at `removal[i]` actually is `i`. That is, the _indexes_ are getting pushed into the array rather than the _values_.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, I noticed that. The original code was using that Array to get the index for the `.splice()`. I don't know why that was being done, but there were several things wrong with the code, so I think most of it was based on misconception.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

**Problem statement:**

```
myArr.splice(2,1);

  \\ [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

now 3 moves at second position and length is reduced by 1 which creates problem.

**Solution:** A simple solution would be iterating in reverse direction when splicing.

```
var i = myArr.length;
while (i--) {
    console.log(myArr);
    myArr.splice(i,1);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1]
[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really the cleanest solution iterating backwards through the while function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `$.each()` function iterates through the array in order from the first element, and internally it sets the index range it will be using at the beginning. So when you remove items from that array it doesn't know you've done so.

You can easily work around this by using a standard `for` statement. If you loop backwards from the end of the list through to the beginning you can remove items without affecting the loop. If you loop forwards you need to adjust the loop counter each time you remove an item from the array.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, modifying the array structure when you are looping through will wreak havoc aplenty. Try using a temporary arrary:

```
var results = ['one', 'two', 'one hundred', 'three'];
var removal = [];
var newResults = [];
$.each(results, function(i) {
    removal.push(i);
    if (results[i].indexOf('one') > -1){
        newResults.push(i);
    } else {
        console.log('Removing:' + results[i] + '(' + removal[i] + ')');
    }
});
results = newResults;
```